# How to get number of likes from a company share with new API rights (from May 12th 2015)

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I'm preparing my application in order to API transition on next May 12th and I found some issues. I would like to know if this behavior is or not normal.

Currently, I'm using permissions: "r_basicprofile", "r_emailaddress", "rw_nus" and "rw_company_admin" and I'm able to post people shares, to post company shares and get shares likes count for both kind of shares.

Now, In order to new documentation, I migrating permissions to "r_basicprofile", "r_emailaddress", "w_share" and "rw_company_admin" and I'm able to post people shares, to post company shares but I cannot get shares likes count for any of both kind of shares.

I understand that it could be normal from people shares because documentation says that a partnership is needed to get this information. However, I don't understand why I cannot get likes count from a company post.

Here and example of xml response of a company request:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{COMPANY_ID}/updates/key={UPDATE-KEY}:(numLikes:())
```

Response before transition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<update> <num-likes>1</num-likes> </update>
```

Response after transition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<update>
</update>
```

Getting more information about the company share (after transition) by using REST-console, I get the following. I think I cannot get like count because linkedin returns that share is likeable ="false".

```
<update>
  <timestamp>1429300558499</timestamp>
  <update-key>{UPDATE-KEY}</update-key>
  <update-type>CMPY</update-type>
  <update-content>
    <company>
      <id>{ID}</id>
      <name>Name</name>
    </company>
    <company-status-update>
      <share>
        <id>s...</id>
        <timestamp>1429300558499</timestamp>
        <visibility>
          <code>anyone</code>
        </visibility>
        <comment>COMMENT</comment>
        <content>
          <submitted-url>URL</submitted-url>
          <shortened-url>URL</shortened-url>
          <title>TITLE</title>
          <description>DESCRIPTION</description>
          <submitted-image-url>URL</submitted-image-url>
          <thumbnail-url>URL</thumbnail-url>
          <eyebrow-url>URL</eyebrow-url>
        </content>
        <source>
          <service-provider>
            <name>LINKEDIN</name>
          </service-provider>
          <service-provider-share-id>s...</service-provider-share-id>
        </source>
      </share>
    </company-status-update>
  </update-content>
  <is-commentable>false</is-commentable>
  <is-likable>false</is-likable>
</update>
```

Do you if we can get likes count without a partner program?

Thanks